# Comparing tensorflow variables.index and variables.data files

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

How can I compare two sets of the TensorFlow files `variables.index` and `variables.data-00000-of-00001`? Is there any utility that will allow me to read them in plain text, or some other way to compare values in these files?

Comment: read them in plain text, or u want to see the values of the variables stored in these files ????

Comment: These are two different files that do not compare. ONE checkpoint is made with 4 files: .ckpt, .index, .meta & .data

Comment: @Tezirg I have two SETS of these two files. I'm trying to compare the corresponding ones

Comment: @inder yes I'd like to compare values in two sets of these two files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to view the tensors stored in the files simply do:

```
from tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint import print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file

print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name="model_name",tensor_name="",all_tensors=True)
```

The output will be something like:

```
tensor_name:  Decoder/decoder/Attention_Wrapper/attention_layer/kernel
[[-0.24866164 -0.0762616   0.02982535 ...  0.14274237 -0.0651149
   0.18989304]
 [ 0.16675466  0.01662545  0.00896074 ... -0.06836775 -0.02540337
   0.0579135 ]
 [-0.34853792  0.05886076  0.21691915 ...  0.03068756  0.37517232
   0.0330036 ]
 ...
 [-0.00463026 -0.05060914 -0.03661629 ...  0.03341271 -0.003078
   0.04194186]
 [ 0.07343228 -0.00445814 -0.01558546 ... -0.0164716  -0.00453405
   0.0168137 ]
 [ 0.03857246 -0.04361508 -0.04800353 ...  0.06200589 -0.05994397
  -0.03183305]]
tensor_name:  Decoder/decoder/Attention_Wrapper/attention_layer/kernel/training_op
[[1.7215452e-08 1.6511342e-08 2.3156689e-08 ... 6.9746142e-09
  3.6705597e-08 6.0520193e-09]
 [2.8541326e-06 9.9242357e-07 4.3421019e-07 ... 8.2636637e-07
  2.9466917e-06 9.2266538e-07]
 [1.4949121e-06 4.0124786e-07 1.8415257e-07 ... 2.1582312e-07
  6.7197351e-07 3.1459973e-07]
 ...
 [3.6029601e-15 1.2615142e-15 4.7981583e-15 ... 5.8665957e-16
  2.0862790e-15 2.4295565e-15]
 [5.8586951e-14 4.5164783e-14 2.6819809e-14 ... 4.2972126e-14
  1.1934837e-13 3.0617263e-14]
 [2.6801797e-15 9.8903675e-16 3.7704488e-16 ... 9.2021988e-16
  2.9194079e-15 9.9945483e-16]]
```